# (Vue) How to solve text broken problem in iPad device

Tags: ios, vue.js, ipad, text, deployment

This problem is occured in specific device(IPad Pro 6 Gen), in certain situation (Occured on first run the App)[image]

The original text is Korean, and error occured like picture above.
In flutter, there are no additional code about language, and also in other device, there are no bugs about language.

I have to fix this error because of IOS app deployment. I received the rejected message about [2.1 - Performance - App completeness, "We are discovered one or more bugs in your app. Specifically text was not properly displayed on the iPad device"].

Is there any method to solve this bug?

Comment: Can you share a MRE?

Comment: @Cabdirashiid Sorry, what is MRE?

Comment: Minimum Reproducible Example, share code how this happens.

Comment: Thank you for comment, and I realize that problem is occured in vue not flutter, so I added UTF-8 code in every vue page temporily. And I will let you know the result later.
Also I want to share code, but I don't know which code exactly the problem, because of whole code is too many, I will share my code If I figure out which code is problem.

Comment: I resolved this question by edit the vue page. So I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the UTF-8 code in every vue page, I can solve the problem.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I add the code above in every page.